# How to draw graph of relationships from binary matrix

Tags: r, matrix, binary

I'm trying to create a graph with relationships of people involved in the 9/11 attacks, but I don't understand the input very much. I use loops to group the hijackers (hijacker1 knows hijacker2; hijacker5 knows hijacker3 etc.) but it doesn't work for me.

The result of my work should be a **relationship graph** as on this page: [LINK](http://www.orgnet.com/tnet.html?fbclid=IwAR06oNJjlYW5cWntnD8vrdmnUeD8l3oikzHVKAWm3fQrBd8vuOaTc50yPZk)

I use data in **csv format**: [Data to download](https://sites.google.com/site/ucinetsoftware/datasets/covert-networks/911hijackers?fbclid=IwAR1v1mbSnrjiI7BND0V_mm5TwJ8CDq82_wELFaIASLXe3XjLVshnmlUBSg8)

The **data schema** looks like the screenshots below. There are three files available, but if I understand correctly to get what I want, enough data from the first file (?) 
[Hijackers ASSOCIATES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69ZE5.png)
[Hijackers ATTR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zURPN.png)
[Hijackers PRIORITY_CONTACT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2QXi.png)

```
       Hname1  HName2  HName3
HName1    0       1       0
HName2    1       0       1
HName3    0       1       0
...
```

I would like to draw a relationship diagram and extract information about which of the hijackers had the most relationships (Should I use `betweenness()` from `igraph` library?).

Comment: It looks like you've created an adjacency matrix. Turn the data into a graph object with [graph_from_adjacency_matrix](https://igraph.org/r/doc/graph_from_adjacency_matrix.html) and then `plot()` the result.

Comment: Thx for answer. I have this error when I use it: `'mde(x)':'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`.

Comment: Ah, you probably have a data.frame, just convey to a matrix with as.matrix()

Comment: I think that you probably want `degree`, not `betweenness`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `igraph`:

First, let's grab the data and make it into an adjacency matrix:

```
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
download.file("https://sites.google.com/site/ucinetsoftware/datasets/covert-networks/911hijackers/9%2011%20Hijackers%20CSV.zip?attredirects=0&d=1",
              temp,
              mode = "wb")
data <- read.csv(unz(temp,"CSV/9_11_HIJACKERS_ASSOCIATES.csv"))

my.rownames <- data$X
data2 <- sapply(data[,-1], as.numeric)
rownames(data2) <- my.rownames
Adj <- as.matrix(data2)
```

Now the easy parts. We can convert the adjacency matrix into an igraph graph, compute vertex degree and add that data to to the graph.

```
library(igraph)
Graph <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(Adj)

V(Graph)$vertex_degree <-  degree(Graph)
```

Finally we can plot the graph with the vertex size being proportional to the degree:

```
plot.igraph(Graph,
            vertex.size = V(Graph)$vertex_degree,
            layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold, main="Hijacker Relationships")
```

[image]